# MobileFirst Server 7.0.0 as service on Windows Server 2012 not recognizing runtime environments

Tags: windows-services, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

We are encountering a problem running the MobileFirst Enterprise Server on Windows Server 2012 R2. When we start using a batch file as Administrator, as long as we stay remote connected the server is working OK, we see the Runtime Environments. But when we log out, server is unreachable. We created a Windows Service that starts the server with same command:

```
*sc create WASLibertyV85 binPath= "C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\bin\server.bat start worklight" DisplayName="IBM WebSphere Liberty V8.5 Worklight" start=auto*
```

But the Runtime is not displayed, we only see:

> No runtime environment deployed in this server.

Is there a way to enable MobileFirst Server seeing the Runtime Environments when was started as service?

Comment: And when you run w/out the Windows service everything is working correctly?

Comment: Except that I don't see the Runtimes, yes.

Comment: Try setting the service to [log on](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#AppNotWorkingFromService) to the account where you can run the batch file normally.

Comment: But you will still run into [Error 1053](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#Error1053) unless you use a service wrapper like Idan Adar advises...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's our complete solution:

**1.    Start CMD as administrator and run this:**

```
sc create WASLibertyV85 binPath= "C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\bin\server.bat start worklight" DisplayName="IBM WebSphere Liberty V8.5 Worklight" start=delayed-auto
```

**2.    under  Services.msc  open the properties of the  „IBM WebSphere Liberty V8.5 Worklight“ service and set this (if not already):**

```
Tab GENERAL -> Startup type: Automatic (Delayed Start)
Tab LOG ON -> Log on as: Local System account + Allow service to interact with desktop
```

++ When the server restarts, it can take up to 2 minutes, until the runtimes are displayed in the Worklight Console!++

Answer (score 0):

MFP is not being run as a service. MFP is simply a web app (a .war file, a .jar file and some artifacts) running on-top of WebSphere Liberty, in your case. So all of this is related only to Liberty and not to MFP.

As long as the Liberty instance is launched correctly, it should handle everything on its own, including the web apps that are deployed to it, MFP being one of them.

You could perhaps follow the instructions provided in [this forum topic](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/7668/liberty-profile-windows-service-apache-commons-daemon.html) explaining how to use Apache Commons Daemon to run Liberty as a Windows service. There are other tools that can do this as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was cause by starting the service with a log on account set as current windows user. When we've chaged to Local System Account and enabled Allow system to interact with desktop, the Runtime became visible on MobileFirst Server.